# Monitoring all emails on a company domain?

Tags: google-workspace, email

We are using Google Apps for Business on a domain that we've bought (from elsewhere). We need to monitor email communication from outside folks to employees.

One solution would be to enable this within each Google mail interface, but that can be changed by each individual.

How can I enable this for the entire domain without it being in control of the user?

Is it possible to set it up so that all emails received by any user on the site are also forwarded to a specified account?

Answer (score 2):

Google offers this as [an add-on to Google Apps for Business](https://gsuite.google.com/products/vault/).

Answer (score 2):

Note: I wouldn't recommend this solution anymore as this seems to be outdated since 2011

There is also something called GAIL that can help.  It allows an admin to login as any user.  I think it just allows you to check out an account, not necessarily all history. It is free, but not officially stable, so obviously won't work for every organization.

The addon mentioned by Patches is probably the best if you have the $$.  It will keep a true archive of all in/out emails, where GAIL doesn't really provide that.

Comment: This link seems broken.

Comment: yep this answer is outdated anyway, but I went ahead and removed the link. I also added a new, more up-to-date answer.

Comment: Actually, that's my bad, the answer got bumped to the front page and I didn't check the date, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that one option for people still interested in this question in 2017 is to use G Suite's built-in "Google Vault" offering. From their FAQ page

> Google Vault lets you retain, hold, search, and export your organization's mail and chat messages. You can also search and export your organization's files in Google Drive. Vault is entirely web-based, so there's no need to install or maintain any software.
>
> Vault is included with the G Suite Enterprise or Business or Education edition. Or you can buy Vault licenses for an additional $5 per user, per month.

https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2462365